# convert orderdate of format m/d/yy to YYYY-MM-DD in R

Tags: r

My orderdate is in factor and i want to convert it into from mm/dd/yy format to YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
 orderdate : Factor w/ 155932 levels "1/1/2017 1:05:00 AM",..: 41 1 1 89 100 102 106 107 119 122 ...
```

I tried couple of things:

```
orders2017$newdate <- (factor(orders2017$orderdate))
orders2017$newdate1 <- as.Date(orders2017$newdate,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

but nothing is working out and giving me new columns as empty. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have values like `"1/1/2017 1:05:00 AM"` then those aren't dates, they are date times, and as such you have to specify formatting characters for both the date and time parts.

So, first you need to get your date times into a form R understands as such (e.g. POSIXct) by specifying all the parts of the date time:

```
test <- as.POSIXct("1/1/2017 1:05:00 AM", format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
test

> test
[1] "2017-01-01 01:05:00 CST"
```

See `?strftime` if you are not familiar with all the formatting placeholders used above, and note the conditions for use of `%I` and `%p`.

Then you can convert the POSIXct vector into the date format you desire

```
format(test, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

> format(test, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
[1] "2017-01-01"
```

A complication for you is that R has converted your character date times into a factor, so you need to convert them back to a character vector before converting to date times. For example (not tested as you didn't supply example data)

```
orders2017 <- transform(orders2017,
                        orderdate = as.POSIXct(as.character(orderdate),
                                               format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
orders2017 <- transform(orders2017,
                        newdate = format(orderdate, format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You were really close with `as.Date(orders2017$newdate,format="%Y-%m-%d")`, you just need to make the `format` string match your actual format.

Your actual format is mm/dd/YYYY, so use `%m/%d/%Y` as the format string:

```
as.Date("1/1/2017 1:05:00 AM", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
# [1] "2017-01-01"
```

Then the default printing of `Date` format objects is what you want.

So for your data,

```
orders2017$newdate1 <- as.Date(orders2017$newdate,format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

The time part will just be ignored.

Comment: Huh! I didn't know `as.Date()` would just ignore all the extra bits.

Comment: Yup! It's all `strptime` under the hood, but from the `?strptime` Details *"Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored."*

Comment: @Gregor Thankyyou so much..It worked but if i also want to include time too what additional should i write?

Comment: @jsingh For the time part, see my answer (which I just undeleted)